# Table environment is not working when I try to make it a custom environment

Tags: tables, environments

I have the following table which compiles perfectly

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=32mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccYYcYY@{}}
        \toprule
                      && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Next State} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output} \\
        \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-7}
        Present State && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$\\
        \midrule
                000   &&  010    &   011   &&   0     &    0    \\
                001   &&  001    &   001   &&   1     &    1    \\
                010   &&  110    &   011   &&   0     &    0    \\
                011   &&  000    &   101   &&   1     &    1    \\[0.5em]
                100   &&  111    &   101   &&   0     &    0    \\
                101   &&  000    &   101   &&   0     &    1    \\
                110   &&  000    &   001   &&   1     &    0    \\
                111   &&  101    &   011   &&   0     &    0    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{State table for the sequential circuit discussed}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Based on this I want to make an environment so I can reuse this table (the number of columns don’t have to change). I have tried defining it like so (I have simply extracted the `begin` and `end` parts of the table and left out the contents):

```
\newenvironment{statetable}%
{\begin{table}[H]\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccYYcYY@{}}
        \toprule
        && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Next State} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output} \\
        \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-7}
        Present State && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
        \midrule}%
{\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{State table for the sequential circuit discussed}%
\end{table}}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
% \begin{statetable}
 000   &&  010    &   011  &&   0    &    0    \\
 001   &&  001    &   001  &&   1    &    1    \\
 010   &&  110    &   011  &&   0    &    0    \\
 011   &&  000    &   101  &&   1    &    1    \\[0.5em]
 100   &&  111    &   101  &&   0    &    0    \\
 101   &&  000    &   101  &&   0    &    1    \\
 110   &&  000    &   001  &&   1    &    0    \\
 111   &&  101    &   011  &&   0    &    0    \\
% \end{statetable}
```

But I get the following error:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.52  000   &
             &  010    &   011  &&   0    &    0    \\
?
```

Comment: I’m on mobile so can’t try this myself, but as a first step for debugging this, I suggest making it more *minimal*. Try a similar thing, but with a much smaller table/custom environment — take out almost all the table content, cut down to 1 or 2 columns, etc. If it still fails then, post that as your MWE — it’ll be much easier for experts to spot the issue. Or if it works when minimised, put the content back in gradually, and see which bit specifically triggers the problem.

Comment: @FirstUser -- the answer below is a rough attempt to point you in the right direction -- reference -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489099/defining-a-custom-environment-with-tabularx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\newenvironment{statetable}% 
{\table
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{cYYYY}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Next State} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
        Present State & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
        \midrule
        }%
{\bottomrule
    \endtabularx
    \caption{State table for the sequential circuit discussed}%
\endtable}


\newenvironment{altstatetable}% 
{\table
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Next State} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output} \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
        Present State & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
        \midrule
        }%
{\bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{State table for the sequential circuit discussed}%
\endtable}


\begin{document}
 \begin{statetable}
 000   &  010    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 001   &  001    &   001  &   1    &    1    \\
 010   &  110    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 011   &  000    &   101  &   1    &    1    \\[0.5em]
 100   &  111    &   101  &   0    &    0    \\
 101   &  000    &   101  &   0    &    1    \\
 110   &  000    &   001  &   1    &    0    \\
 111   &  101    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 \end{statetable}
 
 \begin{altstatetable}
 000   &  010    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 001   &  001    &   001  &   1    &    1    \\
 010   &  110    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 011   &  000    &   101  &   1    &    1    \\[0.5em]
 100   &  111    &   101  &   0    &    0    \\
 101   &  000    &   101  &   0    &    1    \\
 110   &  000    &   001  &   1    &    0    \\
 111   &  101    &   011  &   0    &    0    \\
 \end{altstatetable}

\end{document}
```

---

Using `\begin{tabularx}` and `\end{tabularx}` inside of a `\newenvironment` does not work. This is also explained in the `tabularx` documentation from which the following is quoted:

> This mechanism of grabbing an environment body does have the
> disadvantage (shared with the AMS alignment environments) that you can
> not make extension environments by code such as
>
> ```
> \newenvironment{foo}{\begin{tabularx}{XX}}{\end{tabularx}}
> ```
>
> as the code is looking for a literal string `\end{tabularx}` to stop
> scanning.  Since version 2.02, one may avoid this problem by using
> `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` directly in the definition:
>
> ```
> \newenvironment{foo}{\tabularx{XX}}{\endtabularx}
> ```

I have applied the same technique for the `table` environment, as well.

Additonally, I also removed the redundant empty columns and introduced a gap in the adjacent `\cmidrule` commands using the trim options (`(l)` and `(r)`, for more information on that, see the `booktabs` documentation).

Since you dind't seem to need linebreaks inside of your columns, I decided to add an alternative version of your table using `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep{\fill}}`  and regular `c` type columns instead of `tabularx`.

Comment: Thanks this is working perfectly. I didn't know that you could avoid having to write `\begin{envname}` and `\end{envname}` in the `newenvironment` definition blocks. I can do this for all environments right ? Also could you please tell me what I was doing wrong ?

Comment: @FirstUser: I added some short explanations on what I changed and why. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{environ, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\NewEnviron{note}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccYYcYY@{}}
                \toprule
        Present State && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ && $x = 0$ & $x = 1$\\
        \midrule
        000   &&  010    &   011   &&   0     &    0    \\
                \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx} 
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{note}
        
    \end{note}
\end{document}
```